# Loop Analysis - Analysis of Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity

This question is based off of this resource http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis.

Can someone break down why Exercise 6 letter b is linear? The outer loop seems to be increasing i by a factor of 2 each time, so I would assume it was logarithmic...

From the link:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2)
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      sum++;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a geometric series.
The inner loops runs `i` iterations per iteration of the outer loop, and the outer loop decreases by half each time.

So, summing it up gives you:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1
```

This is [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), with `r=1/2` and `a=n` -  that converges to `a/(1-r)=n/(1/2)=2n`, so:

```
T(n) <= 2n
```

And since `2n` is in `O(n)` - the algorithm runs in linear time.

---

This is a perfect example to see that complexity is NOT achieved by multiplying the complexity of each nested loop (that would have got you `O(nlogn)`), but by actually analyzing how many iterations are needed.

Comment: so in this case 'int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      sum++;'

The outer loop is increasing by a factor of 2 each time and the first term is 1. Therefore '{1,2,4,8}' due to '{a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, ... }' However why isn't it the same for this case?

'int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      sum++;'

Comment: @gmad separate questions should be asked separately, but note that in the second case, the inner loop runs `N` times every time round. So `log N` iterations of the outer, multiplied by `N` iterations of the inner, gives `N log N` as required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its simple
See the value of n is decreasing by half each time and I runs n times.

So for the first time i goes from 1 to n
next time 0 to n/2
and hence 0 to n/k on kth term.

Now total time inner loop would run = Log(n)

So its a GP the number of times i is running.
with terms

```
n,n/2,n/4,n/8....0
```

so we can find the sum of the GP

```
2^(long(n) +1)-1  / (2-1)

2^(long(n)+1) = n
hence n-1/(1) = >O(n)
```

Comment: where did the 2^(log(n)+1) come from? Why is it raised to the power of 2?

Comment: how did you sum up n + (n/2) + (n/4)...?

Comment: it is a GP with common ratio 2(going from the last tearm to n). So the sum of GP is `r^(n+1) -1/(r-1)` so as the number of terms is log(n).So we get this formula. the first term of the GP will be some constant so I ignored it.